# Is it possible to switch sides?

Tags: pc, call-of-duty-black-ops-2

I want to switch sides and play against my friend, but can't see a way to change in online multiplayer. How do I switch my team?

Comment: are you playing on the same screen? I would assume you cannot unless your playing one of the community games like in MW3 (all or nothing, ect.)

Comment: @Ender Thanks for your reply. Just single screen and I find it stupid the developers haven't incorporated it into the game. Lets hope they add it into a future patch.

Comment: I don't own BO2, but in prior titles in the COD series, you could only change teams in custom/local games.

Comment: Would also enable tons of boosters to use this to have a friend on the other team either sit in a corner and kill repeatedly or tell their friend on the other team where they are all at.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, there is no way (and will stay like that) to change teams while you are playing online multiplayer.

If there was ever a way to change teams in BO2, the teams would be unbalanced and the game wouldn't be as fun to play.

Answer (score 2):

You can't exactly switch teams when ever you want. However, you can enter a lobby, and if there are openings, quickly send your friend a game invite. If your friend is quick enough, he will enter the same lobby, but you won't be in a party, so he'll have 6/11 chance of being on the other team.